# Ошибка при установки nestjs-typegoose. Could not resolve dependency: peer @nestjs/common@"^6.10.1 || ^7.0.0" from nestjs-typegoose@7.1.38

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

Нахожусь на стадии изучения бекенда на примере NestJS. Дошел до момента работы с базами данных. Пытался установить nestjs-typegoose. Набрал в консоли npm i nestjs-typegoose
и получил следующую ошибку.

```
Could not resolve dependency:
peer @nestjs/common@"^6.10.1 || ^7.0.0" from nestjs-typegoose@7.1.38
node_modules/nestjs-typegoose
  nestjs-typegoose@"*" from the root project

Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

Raw JSON explanation object:

{
  "code": "ERESOLVE",
  "current": {
    "name": "@nestjs/common",
    "version": "8.4.5",
    "whileInstalling": {
      "name": "top-api",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "path": "/home/dzmitrylukashenka/projects/nestjs/top-api"
    },
    "location": "node_modules/@nestjs/common",
    "isWorkspace": false,
    "dependents": [
      {
        "type": "prod",
        "name": "@nestjs/common",
        "spec": "^8.4.5",
        "from": {
          "location": "/home/dzmitrylukashenka/projects/nestjs/top-api"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "currentEdge": {
    "type": "prod",
    "name": "@nestjs/common",
    "spec": "^8.4.5",
    "from": {
      "location": "/home/dzmitrylukashenka/projects/nestjs/top-api"
    }
  },
  "edge": {
    "type": "peer",
    "name": "@nestjs/common",
    "spec": "^6.10.1 || ^7.0.0",
    "error": "INVALID",
    "from": {
      "name": "nestjs-typegoose",
      "version": "7.1.38",
      "whileInstalling": {
        "name": "top-api",
        "version": "0.0.1",
        "path": "/home/dzmitrylukashenka/projects/nestjs/top-api"
      },
      "location": "node_modules/nestjs-typegoose",
      "isWorkspace": false,
      "dependents": [
        {
          "type": "prod",
          "name": "nestjs-typegoose",
          "spec": "*",
          "from": {
            "location": "/home/dzmitrylukashenka/projects/nestjs/top-api"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "strictPeerDeps": false,
  "force": false
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил в конце `--legacy-peer-deps`. Получилось так

```bash
npm install --save nestjs-typegoose --legacy-peer-deps
```